# Any faster methods for allocating the entries into sparse matrix using armadillo lib in C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo

Literally, I want to put entries - maaaaany entries- into sparse matrix provided by armadillo module.
If I do this like below (B is Na X N^2 Matrix)

```
sp_cx_mat BB(Na*Na, N*N*Na);    
for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++){
    BB(span(i*N, (i + 1)*N - 1), span(i*N*N, (i + 1)*N*N - 1)) = B;
}
```

it takes so much time to do this. (N and Na is about 64 or more like 128~)
Is there any efficient way to make this faster, including kernel or optimisation settings? I'm already using Open BLAS kernel and AVX optimisation setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead in dealing with sparse matrices. They are designed only for very large matrices where the vast majority of the elements (90%+) is zero. The internal representation is essentially a [compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) version of the matrix.

If the total number of elements (zero and non-zero) would fit into available memory, using a normal dense matrix might be faster. Dense matrices not have the overhead of compression.

Sometimes it's simply easier to install more memory or run your algorithms on a bigger machine.